# is there a method to perform a custom TFIDF for sentence negation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

i used TFIDF to compute similarity between articles but i have a problem that it consider that this two sentences are similar :

```
I am against this project
I am for this project
```

how can i ameliorate my approach to take into account this sentence negation please ?

Answer (score 0):

Once I had to encounter this problem. Usually it's hard to solve this problem using tf-idf, rather you need more complex NLP model, i.e. BERT, to find if the sentences are semantically similar or opposite. But if your use case is like your examples, you could do the following.

I am assuming your articles/documents/sentences are as simple as this. So usually you can encounter two types of opposite meaning sentences. One is with  `n't`/`not` tokens and other type is just using opposite word. Using `nltk` library you can find if there are words that are of opposite meaning (antonyms) in two sentences. Then you can decide easily.

Comment: thank you for this response but i dont found  in nltk ?

Comment: I hope [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-synonyms-antonyms-from-nltk-wordnet-in-python) tutorial will help you to figure out how to use `nltk` for finding synonyms/antonyms.

Answer (score 0):

I add on the *msayef*'s comment. You may also want to consider [negative adverbs](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Negative-Adverbs.htm).